# Is there a guide for using Craft Commerce headless?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce3, headless

I’m trying to figure out the work involved in using Craft Commerce in a headless setup. Is it possible? I think so. How do I expose the Commerce functionality via an API, instead of through Twig templates? I don’t know.

I’ve done a general Google search, skimmed the Commerce docs, checked NY 17, and checked CraftQuest. I may have missed something. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the Commerce docs further, I see I can use the GraphQL API to get information from Commerce. That is, at least for products. Craft 3.5 will allow GraphQL mutations so perhaps that’ll encompass some sort of write API to commerce. If not, I’ll have to create custom endpoints in the Craft app to do the following:

- Create customer account
- Edit customer account
- Edit subscription info
- Edit cart
- Checkout

Comment: Hi. How'd you get on with this?